# disable parentheses in access sql queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

is there a way to tell ms access (2003) to *not* put joins into parentheses. or at least to understand them without (every other database does)

i want something like:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM a
INNER JOIN b
        ON a.a = b.a
INNER JOIN c
        ON b.c = c.c
```

but access tells me that the query is wrong. IT’S NOT, and it’s driving me crazy …

it also puts all joins in a single line—impossible to read

thanks in advance.

ps. i already activated ANSI 92 compatibility/support in settings

Comment: Have you tried to create a new query? Maybe I just tested something too simple (Left Outer Join on 2 tables.).

Comment: Yes. I even started it in the graphic design view and switched back-and-forth to SQL text view. They never showed up.

Comment: Why do you care if there are parentheses in there?

Comment: The parens force a separation between the tables being joined and the corresponding `ON` clauses.  In every other major Database Management System, one can write a lengthy sequence of `JOIN`s, placing the `ON` clauses naturally beside the tables being joined.  In Access, the more `JOIN`s are involved, the more you have to count parentheses to pair up join conditions.  Although parentheses are no hindrance to the computer, they can certainly be irritating to human users.

Comment: @ david fenton: exactly what voteydisciple writes. they are highly irritating and make it hard to read (and understand) the queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no.  Access 2003 is just that "dumb" about SQL.  It is "wrong" in that Access can only parse one JOIN, which leaves you with the infuriating (but also still correct):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN (b INNER JOIN c ON b.c = c.c)
    ON a.a = b.a
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that sucks. i still don’t understand why it needs those dumb parentheses though. to me they are really illogical

Comment: Why should anyone give a rat's ass about these parens?

Comment: David W. Fenton: "Why should anyone [care] about these parens?" From the point of view of a human reading the code, they are unnecessary clutter. From the point of view of a human writing code, you may want to force the optimizer to do the join in an explicit order but the Access Database Engine doesn't let you do this (so yet another way in which it does not comply with SQL-92 even in so-called ANSI-92 Query mode <rolls eyes>).

Answer (score 2):

See the Access Help [About ANSI SQL query mode (MDB)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx).

> This mode conforms closely to the
>   ANSI-92 Level 1 specification, but is
>   not ANSI-92 Level 1 compliant.

For "ANSI-92" read "ANSI/ISO SQL-92" (and for "conforms closely to" read "vaguely resembles" ).

Bottom line: you must include the parentheses. Note the Access database engine's optimizer may change the order of the tables as it sees fit.

Comment: (and for "conforms closely to" read "vaguely resembles" ) <-- <3

Answer (score 0):

I just tried SQL Server Compantible Syntax (ANSI 92) and Checked This Database.

I tend to setup all my tables and joins in the graphic query builder and then customize in the SQL editor while working around all the parentheses. The usage of square brackets drives me crazy as well. I'm lucky, most of the apps in my firm are being migrated from Access to SQL Server.

Comment: yes, me too. all those parens and brackets are driving me nuts.

Comment: I certainly agree that if you hate Access and don't want to work by its conventions you should without question stop using it and use something else. But it's your loss.

Comment: backend is on an ms sql server, frontend is access. why? because customers want it that way