# Update a single table based on multiple tables - appears to works MySql not ACCESS 2003

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

Mysql Version Works

```
UPDATE results SET rCARRIER = (
    SELECT cellCarrierName
    FROM tblImportedTempTable, user, cellCarrier
    WHERE
        userEmployeeNumber = tblImportedTempTable.EMPLOYEENUMBER
        AND userId = results.rUserId
        AND results.rPHONENUMBER = tblImportedTempTable.PHONENUMBER
        AND CARRIER = cellCarrierId )
```

I have written this sql that works fine in MySql(above) and fails in access 2003(below) any suggestions? Is one or both of the 2 nonstandard sql? Does Access hav an admin problem?

Sorry the field and table names are diferent this is the ACCESS version.

Access version

```
UPDATE tblWorkerPhoneNumber SET tblWorkerPhoneNumber.PhoneCarrier = (
    SELECT PhoneCarrierType.CarrierName
    FROM tblImportedPhoneCarrier, tblWorkerMaster, PhoneCarrierType
    WHERE
        tblWorkerMaster.EmployeeNumber = tblImportedPhoneCarrier.Emp
        AND tblWorkerMaster.WorkerID = tblWorkerPhoneNumber.WorkerID
        AND tblWorkerPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber = tblImportedPhoneCarrier.Cell
        AND tblImportedPhoneCarrier.CarrierCode = PhoneCarrierType.CarrierID )
```

Error Message
Operation must use and updateable query

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322504/how-to-create-a-correlated-update-subquery-in-ms-access perhaps

Comment: Well, the example in the other question does use a join, so I suppose so.  I don't have any idea about the idiosyncrasies of Access SQL personally, however, that's why I just linked to another question that seems the same rather than giving an actual answer :)

Comment: Let us assume Accesss works fine with joins. I do not have much experience with SQL with any database. Should I be able to convert the SQL statement I am trying to use to joins?

Comment: Can you get your select statement to work by itself?

Comment: Your "Access version" above looks to be a vanilla SQL-92 `UPDATE` with a scalar subquery. Sadly, Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) doesn't support the SQL-92 Standard. For more details, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231350/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access/1238335#1238335).

Comment: The fastest way around this kind of problem in Access is simply to write the subquery out to a temp table. There might be a SQL workaround, but you're going to spend a lot more time figuring that out than it will take to work around it with a temp table.

Comment: Jeff actually the select did not work in mysql because it did not know results but the update worked fine.

Comment: David and onedaywhen I Know almost nothing about Access and we are about to move from 2003 to 2010. For this current project we are just going to update by hand. Do you happen to know if Access 2010 does a better job supporting SQL-92?

Comment: So far as I am aware, ANSI 92 SQL support is identical in A2003 and A2010, and neither is terribly good from the standpoint of the ANSI 92 SQL purist. I wouldn't depend on it in any Access application, myself, since it introduces a number of problems that break existing Access apps.

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, something like this:

```
UPDATE tblWorkerPhoneNumber 
INNER JOIN tblWorkerMaster ON tblWorkerMaster.WorkerID = tblWorkerPhoneNumber.WorkerID  
INNER JOIN tblImportedPhoneCarrier ON tblWorkerPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber = tblImportedPhoneCarrier.Cell   
INNER JOIN PhoneCarrierType ON tblImportedPhoneCarrier.CarrierCode = PhoneCarrierType.CarrierID
SET tblWorkerPhoneNumber.PhoneCarrier = PhoneCarrierType.CarrierName  
WHERE tblWorkerMaster.EmployeeNumber = tblImportedPhoneCarrier.Emp
```

(Might need to change the join conditions; I'm not familiar with your schema)

Comment: Works great in MySql. Though I can not get it to work in Access 2003. Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, due to time constraints, I think I will just do it by hand.

Comment: I think it might need parentheses to make it work with Access 2003  but I still have not succeeded. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328544/disable-parentheses-in-access-sql-queries